# Arguments of npm script

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-scripts, npm-run

I have following package.json file:

```
.....
"scripts": {
  "script1": "node script1.js",
  "script2": "npm run script1 && node script2.js"
},
.....

> npm run script2 --port '8081'
```

Now, flag `--port` is used only in script2.
How can I pass this flag in script1?

Comment: A cross-platform solution is to run; `npm run script2 -- --port 8081` - Note the additional `--` between the `npm run script2` command and your arguments `--port 8081`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found its easier to use environment variables in cases like this:

```
PORT=8081 npm run script2
```

Then have your scripts use that variable like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "script1": "node script2.js --port=${PORT:-8080}",
  "script2": "npm run script1 && node script2.js --port=${PORT:-8080}"
}
```

Comment: This is ok when running on _*nix_ platforms because the default shell that npm utilizes for npm scripts is `sh`. However Command Substitution, i.e. `${...}`, on Windows will fail because typically the default shell that npm utilizes for npm scripts is `cmd`,

Comment: This is true. I've just accepted that and use Ubuntu on Windows always. I've given up on cmd and hope someday windows will as well.